# How to get rid of username confirmation when using Google repo?

Tags: bash, repository

I want have a patch run every Monday to get the latest Android source code and have it built. It seems everything goes well except I have to help 'repo' to confirm my username and email when I get the patch run. The patch will be scheduled in midnight so I guess I have no chance to offer my help to confirm it... How could I configure repo to dismiss the step? Otherwise, is there any way to input 'enter' by bash script once the script gets prompt?

Comment: How do you get patches? If you're using git over ssh, set up ssh keys :) They're wonderful. If it is another mechanism, you might need to use [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to script the interaction.

Answer (score 2):

[repo](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) simply builds on top of [git](http://git.or.cz/).

To set your name in git,

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

Comment: I have it configured, of course. However, repo ask me to confirm if the configuration is correct...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by 'expect', here is the script looks like

```
expect - << EOF
exec repo init -u ssh://${USER}@<your_repo_server>/<your_manifest.git>
exepect “Your name \[Your Name\]:"
send "\r"
expect "Your Email" \[Your@email.com\]:"
send “\r"
expect "is this correct \[y/n\]?"
send "y\r"
EOF
```

Comment: Please fix quotation marks: s/“/"; s/exepect/expect/. Thanks :-).